# Find base price and options increments/decrements from their prices

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Maybe the title is not clear, so let me explain:

I have a product with several options, each option changing the price (increasing or decreasing it):

```
 - Winter Boots + Red + Small + Leather = 105$
 - Winter Boots + Red + Small + Down = 125$
 - Winter Boots + Green + Small + Leather = 85$
 - Winter Boots + Green + Small + Down = 105$
 - Winter Boots + Red + Big + Leather = 110$
 - Winter Boots + Red + Big + Down = 130$
 - Winter Boots + Green + Big + Leather = 90$
 - Winter Boots + Green + Big + Down = 110$
```

Given all this data, I want to find the base price and how much each option adds or subtracts from it

For example, the result should find base price being $100

The *Red* option adds $10

The *Small* option takes away $10

The *Leather* option adds $5

And so on for every option (Red, Big, Down)

Comment: The given data does not determine the prices uniquely.  Note, for example, that you can add $\$3$ to the base price and subtract $\$1$ from each option without altering the equations.

Comment: I see. What if I know the base price?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of redundancies in the data.  For example, grouping them in consecutive pairs, each pair just tells you that Leather-Down=$\$20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These equations are very redundant, which means there are lots of solutions.

To see this, note, happily, that each variable begins with a different letter.  We note from the first pair that $$D-L=20\;\;\Rightarrow D=L+20$$. 
Similarly, the first and third equations tell us that $$R-G=20\;\;\Rightarrow R=G+20$$

Similarly, the first and fifth equations tell us that $$B-S=5\;\;\Rightarrow B=S+5$$

If we now specify $L,G,S$ at random then $D,R,B$ are determined and we can solve for $$W=85-(L+G+S)$$

Nor does it help much to specify $W$ externally.  As you can see from the above, that just amounts to knowing $L+G+S$ so you'll still have two degrees of freedom.

Comment: Great explanation. I can see it clearly now. Thanks